# Fluent Nhibernate saving child entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, fluent-nhibernate, viewmodel

I'm having following situation. One property object which holds Photos List collection, and Photo object can reference one or more property objects.
So I have mapping like this, which I think is fine

```
public PropertyMap()
{
  Table("Property");
  Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
  Map(x => x.Title).Length(255).Not.Nullable();
  HasMany(x => x.Photos).KeyColumn("Id");
}

public PhotoMap()
 {
    Table("Photo");
    Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
    Map(x => x.Version);
    Map(x => x.ImageData).CustomSqlType("VARBINARY(MAX)").Length(160000);
    Map(x => x.ImageMimeType);
    References( x => x.Property ) 
        .Column('PhotoId')
        .Cascade.All();
 }
```

Data flow of my scenario is
User enters data in some form and choose up to five image per one property create data.
That data are send to HttpPost controller which receives PropertyViewModel newData, and IEnumerable images. Than if modelstate is ok, I open session and transaction and sends this data to domain model and than save this data to db. 
**Everything is ok, except images are not saved? No error thrown, in debug mode images are passed regulary.**

Here is code Create controller and inside PropertyViewModel ToDomainModel() method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(PropertyViewModel newData, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> images)           
 {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       using (/// open session)
       {
          using (// using transaction)
          {
             MyDomain.Property model = new MyDomain.Property();
             newData.ToDomainModel(model, images);

            tx.Commit();
            session.Save(model);
          }
       }
       return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else
    {
       return View(newData);
    }
 }
```

And in ToDomainModel inside ViewModel I receive images together with other data and try to add them to model.Photos collection and save them.

```
 public void ToDomainModel(Property x, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> Images)
    {
        x.Id = Id;            

        List<Photo> Photos = new List<Photo>();
        foreach (var image in Images)
        {
            if (image != null && image.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                Photo p = new Photo();
                p.Property = x;
                p.ImageMimeType = image.ContentType;
                p.ImageData = new byte[image.ContentLength];
                image.InputStream.Read(p.ImageData, 0, image.ContentLength);

                Photos.Add(p);
            }
        }
        x.Photos = Photos;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the `Cascade.All()` to your `HasMany` mapping in `PropertyMap`, not to the `References` in `PhotoMap`, because you are saving the `Property` instance and need to cascade its collections to also save its children.

Comment: OK, Now my propertyMap have 
HasMany(x => x.Photos).KeyColumn("Id").Cascade.All();

And PhotoMap have 
References(x => x.Property).Column("PhotoId");

Now on saving I'm getting 
Invalid column name 'PhotoId'.

Comment: @user313378: There is no column `PhotoId` in your `Photo` table. You need to specify the column in `Photo` that references the parent table `Property`. Most likely, this column is called `PropertyId`.